# Encoding ed25519 issues

Tags: node, base58

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var ed25519 = require('./');

const seed = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const keyPair = ed25519.MakeKeypair(seed);
const base58encoded = base58.encode(keyPair.publicKey);

console.log('base58 pub key: ' + base58encoded);
```

When I run the above code, it shows me the following error

> ed25519.MakeKeypair is not a function

Can anyone please guide me on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Try [pytezos](https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/):

```
>>> from pytezos import Key
>>> public_key = 'edpku976gpuAD2bXyx1XGraeKuCo1gUZ3LAJcHM12W1ecxZwoiu22R'
>>> pytezos.Key.from_public_point(public_key.encode()).public_key_hash()
'tz1KtUYJRPHCYiakAji1pfi6JyjZngYmReKF'
```